# Получение значения из таксономии по фильтру в WP

Tags: php, wordpress

Имеется 2 кастомных типа записей, к обоим прикреплена одна и та же таксономия. Можно ли как то получить Значения таксономий используемые в конкретном типе поста. В голову приходит только быдло код -> получить все посты, по id поста получать категорию и добавлять в массив, если такой еще нет в нем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не надо быдлокодить, лучше почитать [документацию](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query). Всё предусмотрено:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'ваш_тип_поста',
    // Другие параметры запроса
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Когда получите посты указанного вами типа с пощью такого запроса, в цикле по этим постам используйте [wp_get_post_terms()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_get_post_terms), чтобы получить термины указанной таксономии, относящиеся к данному посту. Складывайте эти термины в массив.

После выхода из цикла по постам, прогоните массив через [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-unique.php).

Comment: Таким образом я получу посты по нужному типу поста, а мне нужно получить значения таксономии которые используются в данном типе поста. Сложность возникает в том что я не могу просто взять и отфильтровать те у которых записи пустые, потому что в другом типе поста они заполнены, следовательно и в этом тоже считаются заполненными, потому что это одна и та же таксономия

Comment: Я полагал, что другие параметры $args для извлечения таксономии у вас уже  написаны. Вы должны выбрать записи, у которых нужный тип поста И нужная таксономия. Проблемы не вижу.

Comment: Ок. Полез дальше смотреть документацию, до меня так и не доходит как получить список значений таксономии которые используются в записях нужного типа

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Ну впринципе я так и хотел, может просто не правильно выразился. Всеровно придется в цикле запускать функцию получение терминов поста, а это я так понимаю обращение к базе. Я просто новичек в этом и мне показалось что это будет не очень хорошо в массиве пробегаться по всем постам и обращаться к базе каждый раз получая термины, ну если допустим будет 100-200 постов

Comment: Придумал обратный способ. Можно получить список всех терминов и далее получать все посты по термину в цикле, если количество постов больше 0, то следовательно переходим к проверке следующего термина, иначе убираем из массива. Терминов у нас явно меньше, чем постов и это по в теории должно быстрее работать, как мне кажется

Comment: Можно и так. И ещё 10 способами )) В теории, если у вас меньше 1000 постов, всё будет работать одинаково быстро.